# Specific event when a Component Presentation is inserted in a XPM page

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

Somebody knows what is the event that could capture the insertion of a Component Presentation in a Page? 
I would need it to save the page previously it renders the Templates (Component and Page) code.

I've seen that the method *Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Views.EditorView.prototype._addNewComponentPresentations* is executed when you drag a Component to the page, and I would like to active my "page.save(true)" when this Component is inserted into the Component Presentation list and before the template code is executed again (in the UpdatePreview action). This is the code that insert the new Component into the Page:

```
listComponentPresentations.insertItems(componentPresentationIndex, components, componentTemplateId, this);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would help if you **edit** your question and clarify that you are looking for an event in the UI extension framework as to me that wasn't very clear in your question.